# C: Correct Way to Statically / Dynamically Link with MinGW-w64

Tags: windows, gcc, dynamic-linking, mingw-w64

**Intuitively:**

- MinGW-w64 is a Windows port of the GNU compiler tools (GCC, etc.).
- Pre-compiled binaries for Windows are `.dll` (dynamic linking) / `.lib` (static linking).
- However, MinGW-w64 uses the GNU compiler tools, it would follow that `.so` / `.a` binaries are required.

**What I've Found:**

- According to [Red Hat Enterprise Linux documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/win32.html), seems that MinGW/MinGW-w64/Cygwin linkers look for [`.dll`s and `.a`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15852677/5209610)
- According to [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/84461/mingw-static-and-dynamic-libraries), you should dynamically link to `.so` and statically link to `.a`.
- One question on SO indicates you can [statically link a `.lib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34902737/5209610) and another on SO [says it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12155751/5209610).

Unfortunately, I can't find explicit documentation from MinGW & MinGW-w64 that says what's right and what's wrong when dynamically/statically linking libraries.

In my experience, I have always been able to dynamically link to `.dll`s. Once, I was able to statically link to a `.lib` (using the `-static` flag).

**Question:**

Are `.dll` / `.a` binaries appropriate to dynamically and statically link libraries when compiling with the MinGW-w64 GCC tool-chain? In other words, dynamic libraries generated for MSVC and static libraries generated for GCC?

Comment: That's surprising that it worked, given [this mailing list question](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Answer%2064%20bit%20MSVC-generated%20x64%20.lib/). Also, for GCC on MinGW targets, you have .a for archive libraries (like Linux does) and .dll for dynamic libraries (like Windows does).

Comment: [Source for a/dll files and how the linker uses them (use your browser's Find Text feature to find _direct linking_)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/win32.html)

Comment: Despite the name, MinGW-w64 compiles for 32-bit by default. (You can choose 64-bit version of it manually in the installer.) From my experience, MinGW-w64 works more or less like plain MinGW.

Comment: Because in the installer there is a combobox to choose between `i686` and `x86_64`, and the first one is chosen by default.

Comment: I don't have a source stating that things work the same unfortunately, but I doubt there was ever a reason to change it, and that source I provided was for Cygwin. Sorting through the source code of GCC revealed the file libgcc/config/i386/t-slibgcc-cygming containing the line `SHLIB_EXT = .dll`. The cygming files are common to MinGW, MinGW-w64, and both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Cygwin, so you at least know that [`.so` isn't a possibility](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2734).

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Do you know if the `cygming` file is something I can find on my installation of MinGW-w64, to confirm that this is the case for my system? Or is this a piece of source code that isn't packaged with the MinGW suite?

Comment: [It is a file in the GCC source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/config/i386/t-slibgcc-cygming). Click the link to view the file, comments included. A simple way to solve the .dll/.a issue on your own is to search your MinGW-w64 install directory (e.g. `C:\mingw`) for files with the `.a` or `.dll` file extensions and to search for `.so`, which shouldn't appear. You can also search for `.lib` if you wish, but that won't appear either.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That means that MinGW/MinGW-w64/Cywgin require `.dll` for dynamic linking and `.a` for static linking. If that's the case, you've answered the question. However, it's still very weird that they follow 1) an MSVC library generation convention for dynamically linked binaries and 2) a GCC convention for statically linked binaries. Do you think that the extension is arbitrary (i.e., build libraries with MSVC, GCC, MinGW, whatever - sometimes, they'll all link just fine with MinGW?)

Comment: The extension for dynamic libraries comes from Windows. GCC can generate DLLs just like any other compiler that allows you to create shared libs on Windows. The extension for static libraries comes from the `ar` archive program included with binutils. You can use `ar -t libxxx.a` for example to list the object files contained within any static library. You can also create a DLL file with a MinGW toolchain and generate a `.def` file for the DLL using [`gendef`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gendef/), allowing MSVC tools to create an import library in the native MSVC `.lib` format.

Comment: ... However, the GNU binutils `.a` and MSVC `.lib` static library formats are incompatible; I've never tried mixing the `.obj` files output by MSVC and the `.o` files output by gcc, so it might be possible that you could extract the `.o` files from a `.a` file and add those to the command line for MSVC. C++ code might have a problem due to the incompatible ABI, but C code shouldn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The Answer:**

MinGW / MinGW-w64's port of [GCC's linker `ld` can](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/win32.html):

- directly link to `.dll`s for dynamic linking
- indirectly link to `.dll.a`s for dynamic linking (using import library at compilation)
- link to `.a`s for static linking.

**Why does MinGW / MinGW-w64's port of the GCC linker look for `.dll`?**

In short, the best answer is because that's `.dll`s are Microsoft's answer for shared objects on their 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. On Windows, MinGW / MinGW-w64's port uses Microsoft C runtime (`msvcrt.dll`) [[1]](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/39p86k/q_can_some_one_explain_the_difference_between/cs588cb/), so it obeys Windows OS linker rules.

> Dynamic-link library (or DLL) is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows and OS/2 operating systems. -- [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)

So, to dynamically link libraries you'll use the file extension:

1. `.so` for shared libraries on Linux because that's what the GCC binutils' linker searches for,
2. or `.dll` for shared libraries on Windows because that's what the MinGW / MinGW-w64 port of GCC binutils' linker searches for.

The extension used by the MinGW port of GCC for shared library objects is explicitly listed in a `cygming` file in the source code. As @ChronoKitsune commented, specifically: `SHLIB_EXT = .dll` in [`libgcc/config/i386/t-slibgcc-cygming`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/config/i386/t-slibgcc-cygming). The `cygming` files (for Cygwin and MinGW) are common to MinGW, MinGW-w64, and both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Cygwin. Therefore, this is true for all ports of the GCC binutils to Windows.

**Why does the MinGW / MinGW-w64 linker handle `.lib` then?**

In principle, the GCC binutils' linker won't recognize a `.lib` as a static library. However, it is possible that the linker is smart enough to link against the `.dll` that a `.lib` imports (in the case that the `.lib` is actually an import library). For instance, in the case that a library has dependencies which are linked dynamically that library will be linked dynamically (and [flags to "force" static linking will be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853231/5209610)).

In such cases, I'd imagine that the linker would not throw any errors and it would appear as though the `.lib` was actually linked successfully.

**How do import libraries work? (freebie)**

On Windows, a `.lib` can be one of two libraries:

1. An *import* library generated by the compiler from a `.dll` with all needed definitions for symbol resolution during compilation (however, function implementations are left out) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17602173/5209610)

   1. If you attempt to generate import libraries for a `xxxx.dll` with MinGW / MinGW-w64's port of GCC binutils, it will produce a `libxxxx.dll.a`. The extension file extension is useful for distinguishing an *import* library from a fully-defined *static* library. When compiling with MSVC, this [distinction isn't apparent in the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6402586/5209610)
2. A fully-defined static library

`.lib`s serve a dual purpose because, as @ChronoKitsune commented, the MSVC linker does not directly link against `.dll`s. Instead, an import library is necessary to resolve symbol definitions at compilation, so that the `.dll` is not loaded until run-time:

> An import library (.LIB files) to link with. (The linker creates the import library when the DLL is built.) -- [VS 2015 Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx)

**Why does MinGW/ MinGW-w64's port of the GCC linker look for `.a`?**

This is simple - the port make use of the `ar` archiving utility that is used on *-nix systems, as @ChronoKitsune commented:

> The extension for static libraries comes from the `ar` (archive) program included with binutils. You can use `ar -t libxxx.a` to list the object files contained within any static library.

This is similar to the `lib` command for MSVC, `lib /list foo.lib` This command will return a list of `.obj` files inside if the `.lib` is a static library.