# Error during compilation C code generated by Cython bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'

Tags: cython, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile C code generated from Python code (hello world) and I'm stuck on one error.
I'm using mingw32-w64. After many errors now I'm using this command

```
gcc -DMS_WIN64 -I Python38\include -o test.exe test.c -lpython38 -lm -L Python38\libs -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Wl,--enable-auto-import
```

But I'm getting error

```
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ImportError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x307): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_AttributeError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x59c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_RuntimeError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ImportError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xc23): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_NameError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xcb9): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_CheckRecursionLimit'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xd22): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_CheckRecursionLimit'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xd32): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_CheckRecursionLimit'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xd40): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_CheckRecursionLimit'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xd8a): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_SystemError'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xfc4): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_FalseStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0xfcd): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_TrueStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x101f): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_FalseStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x1037): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_FalseStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x1044): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_TrueStruct'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x17c0): undefined reference to `__imp_PyModule_Type'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x17d8): undefined reference to `__imp_PyModule_Type'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x18d4): undefined reference to `__imp_PyBaseObject_Type'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x1e92): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_DeprecationWarning'
C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o:test.c:(.text+0x1ee9): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
c:/users/ja/documents/winbuilds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqKHihT.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using Python 3.8.4 x86_64-w64-mingw32 Windows 10

Comment: Is there a reason you're not having Cython itself perform the compilation? Manually running the compiler risks omitting crucial flags (e.g. I suspect an issue with PIC/non-PIC code in this case).

Comment: Because I'm looking for a way to 'compile' python to exe (without using things such py2exe). I didn't know Cython can do this

Comment: IIRC -L option should come before -l that needs it. Your problems probably start with python-lib not being found.

Comment: I'm getting same error even with -I at the end. When using python 3.5 I'm not getting error, but I'm unable to run exe because of Windows error `This app can't run on this PC`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use GCC to compile Python modules on Windows any more. I think you have to use MSVC for reasons related to incompatible C runtime libraries. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/63989259/5769463